# Why does the application work on API 19, but does not work on API 26? Target API 28

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdcard

Why does the application work on API 19, but does not work on API 26? Target API 28

Logcat:

```
  2018-10-24 23:09:57.577 10744-10744/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.guahoo.tarotoftheday17, PID: 10744
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 196247420 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 130MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
   .....and further
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used images in your app?  The error is that it is take a lot of memory while you don't have enogh memory on your device or emulator? To solve the image problem compress image size then use it. And it will work

Comment: Yes, I do. Enough in png format. But the application works on both emulators and API 19 devices.

Comment: maybe he lacks any permissions? For example, to record data or use a calendar?

Comment: OutOfMemoryError the error says it self. something that you are using is large in size due to which the error is causing.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to reduce the size of images